# Name of some commutative ring akin to $p$-adics

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

I need help in identifying the naming convention of some commutative ring described below.

Let $p$ be a prime, let $k$ be a positive integer, and let $$\textbf{e} = (e_0,\ldots,e_{k-1})$$ be a list of positive integers. For each $u\ (0\leq u \leq k)$, define
$$
E_{u} = \sum_{0 \leq w < u} e_w
$$ to be the $u$-th prefix sum of $\textbf{e}$. In my work, I have encountered the set of finite series of the following form: 
$$
\sum_{0\leq u < k} \alpha_u p^{E_u}
$$ where
$$
\alpha_u \in \{0,\ldots, p^{e_u}-1\}.
$$

Without distracting the reader with the details of addition and multiplication, I was hoping that such a set looks familiar to the audience.
For example, when $e_u = 1$ for all $u$, then we have (up to isomorphism) the familiar representation of the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

I have searched the literature for some detail/background on the naming convention of such representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{E_k}\mathbb{Z}$--without success.  Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Every integer between $0$ and $p^{E_k}-1$ will have a unique representation as a series of this form. Is the ring you have in mind just $\mathbb{Z}/p^{E_k}\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes; however, the representation of the integer is of particular interest to me.

Comment: Allow me to clarify:  I am looking for the naming convention of such representations of $$\mathbb{Z}/p^{E_k}\mathbb{Z}$$ (if such a thing exists)

Comment: This is an example of a [mixed radix numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix)